# Adding translate class to mobile navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to javascript and I don't quite know where I should be adding in my class that allows for the website to be translated.

I have a mobile nav that appears when the screen width is X small and in that nav I have numerous directional buttons that lead to other parts of the website, BUT two buttons (The english and Chinese translation buttons) don't work when being pressed.

I assume this is because I have not added the 'lang' class in my 'is-mobile' class but I am unaware of how to do this.

Here is my code

```js
(function($) {

  var $window = $(window),
    $body = $('body'),
    $header = $('#header'),
    $banner = $('#banner'),

    settings = {

      banner: {

        // Indicators (= the clickable dots at the bottom).
        indicators: true,

        // Transition speed (in ms)
        // For timing purposes only. It *must* match the transition speed of "#banner > article".
        speed: 1500,

        // Transition delay (in ms)
        delay: 5000,

        // Parallax intensity (between 0 and 1; higher = more intense, lower = less intense; 0 = off)
        parallax: 0.25

      }

    };

  /**
   * Applies parallax scrolling to an element's background image.
   * @return {jQuery} jQuery object.
   */
  $.fn._parallax = (browser.name == 'ie' || browser.name == 'edge' || browser.mobile) ? function() {
    return $(this)
  } : function(intensity) {

    var $window = $(window),
      $this = $(this);

    if (this.length == 0 || intensity === 0)
      return $this;

    if (this.length > 1) {

      for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++)
        $(this[i])._parallax(intensity);

      return $this;

    }

    if (!intensity)
      intensity = 0.25;

    $this.each(function() {

      var $t = $(this),
        on, off;

      on = function() {

        $t.css('background-position', 'center 100%, center 100%, center 0px');

        $window
          .on('scroll._parallax', function() {

            var pos = parseInt($window.scrollTop()) - parseInt($t.position().top);

            $t.css('background-position', 'center ' + (pos * (-1 * intensity)) + 'px');

          });

      };

      off = function() {

        $t
          .css('background-position', '');

        $window
          .off('scroll._parallax');

      };

      breakpoints.on('<=medium', off);
      breakpoints.on('>medium', on);

    });

    $window
      .off('load._parallax resize._parallax')
      .on('load._parallax resize._parallax', function() {
        $window.trigger('scroll');
      });

    return $(this);

  };


  /**
   * @return {jQuery} jQuery object.
   */
  $.fn._slider = function(options) {

    var $window = $(window),
      $this = $(this);

    if (this.length == 0)
      return $this;

    if (this.length > 1) {

      for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++)
        $(this[i])._slider(options);

      return $this;

    }

    // Vars.
    var current = 0,
      pos = 0,
      lastPos = 0,
      slides = [],
      indicators = [],
      $indicators,
      $slides = $this.children('article'),
      intervalId,
      isLocked = false,
      i = 0;

    // Turn off indicators if we only have one slide.
    if ($slides.length == 1)
      options.indicators = false;

    // Functions.
    $this._switchTo = function(x, stop) {

      if (isLocked || pos == x)
        return;

      isLocked = true;

      if (stop)
        window.clearInterval(intervalId);

      // Update positions.
      lastPos = pos;
      pos = x;

      // Hide last slide.
      slides[lastPos].removeClass('top');

      if (options.indicators)
        indicators[lastPos].removeClass('visible');

      // Show new slide.
      slides[pos].addClass('visible').addClass('top');

      if (options.indicators)
        indicators[pos].addClass('visible');

      // Finish hiding last slide after a short delay.
      window.setTimeout(function() {

        slides[lastPos].addClass('instant').removeClass('visible');

        window.setTimeout(function() {

          slides[lastPos].removeClass('instant');
          isLocked = false;

        }, 100);

      }, options.speed);

    };

    // Indicators.
    if (options.indicators)
      $indicators = $('<ul class="indicators"></ul>').appendTo($this);

    // Slides.
    $slides
      .each(function() {

        var $slide = $(this),
          $img = $slide.find('img');

        // Slide.
        $slide
          .css('background-image', 'url("' + $img.attr('src') + '")')
          .css('background-position', ($slide.data('position') ? $slide.data('position') : 'center'));

        // Add to slides.
        slides.push($slide);

        // Indicators.
        if (options.indicators) {

          var $indicator_li = $('<li>' + i + '</li>').appendTo($indicators);

          // Indicator.
          $indicator_li
            .data('index', i)
            .on('click', function() {
              $this._switchTo($(this).data('index'), true);
            });

          // Add to indicators.
          indicators.push($indicator_li);

        }

        i++;

      })
      ._parallax(options.parallax);

    // Initial slide.
    slides[pos].addClass('visible').addClass('top');

    if (options.indicators)
      indicators[pos].addClass('visible');

    // Bail if we only have a single slide.
    if (slides.length == 1)
      return;

    // Main loop.
    intervalId = window.setInterval(function() {

      current++;

      if (current >= slides.length)
        current = 0;

      $this._switchTo(current);

    }, options.delay);

  };

  // Breakpoints.
  breakpoints({
    xlarge: ['1281px', '1680px'],
    large: ['981px', '1280px'],
    medium: ['737px', '980px'],
    small: ['481px', '736px'],
    xsmall: [null, '480px']
  });

  // Play initial animations on page load.
  $window.on('load', function() {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      $body.removeClass('is-preload');
    }, 100);
  });

  // Mobile?
  if (browser.mobile)
    $body.addClass('is-mobile', 'tr');

  else {

    breakpoints.on('>medium', function() {
      $body.removeClass('is-mobile');
    });

    breakpoints.on('<=medium', function() {
      $body.addClass('is-mobile');



    });

  }


  // Dropdowns.
  $('#nav > ul').dropotron({
    alignment: 'center',
    hideDelay: 400
  });

  // Header.
  if ($banner.length > 0 &&
    $header.hasClass('alt')) {

    $window.on('resize', function() {
      $window.trigger('scroll');
    });

    $banner.scrollex({
      bottom: $header.outerHeight(),
      terminate: function() {
        $header.removeClass('alt');
      },
      enter: function() {
        $header.addClass('alt');
      },
      leave: function() {
        $header.removeClass('alt');
        $header.addClass('reveal');
      }
    });

  }

  // Banner.
  $banner._slider(settings.banner);

  // Off-Canvas Navigation.

  // Navigation Panel Toggle.
  $('<a href="#navPanel" class="navPanelToggle"></a>')
    .appendTo($header);

  // Navigation Panel.
  $(
      '<div id="navPanel">' +
      '<nav>' +
      $('#nav').navList() +
      '</nav>' +
      '<a href="#navPanel" class="close"></a>' +
      '</div>'
    )
    .appendTo($body)
    .panel({
      delay: 500,
      hideOnClick: true,
      hideOnSwipe: true,
      resetScroll: true,
      resetForms: true,
      side: 'right'
    });


  // onclick behavior
  $('.lang').click('touchstart', function() {
    var lang = $(this).attr('id'); // obtain language id

    // translate all translatable elements
    $('.tr').each(function(i) {
      $(this).text(aLangKeys[lang][$(this).attr('key')]);
    });

  });

  document.getElementById('ch').onclick = function() {
    var lang = $(this).attr('id'); // obtain language id

    // translate all translatable elements
    $('.tr').each(function(i) {
      $(this).text(aLangKeys[lang][$(this).attr('key')]);
    });


  }

  // preparing language file
  var aLangKeys = new Array();
  aLangKeys['en'] = new Array();
  aLangKeys['ch'] = new Array();

  aLangKeys['en']['home'] = 'Home';
  aLangKeys['en']['about'] = 'About Us';
  aLangKeys['en']['serv'] = 'Services';
  aLangKeys['en']['sem'] = 'Search Engine Marketing';
  aLangKeys['en']['webdev'] = 'Website Development';
  aLangKeys['en']['app'] = 'Mobile App Development';
  aLangKeys['en']['tbd'] = 'Technical Business Development';
  aLangKeys['en']['ourteam'] = 'Our Team';
  aLangKeys['en']['contactus'] = 'Contact Us';
  aLangKeys['en']['submit'] = 'Send Message';
  aLangKeys['en']['reset'] = 'Reset';



  aLangKeys['ch']['home'] = '首页';
  aLangKeys['ch']['about'] = '关于我们';
  aLangKeys['ch']['serv'] = '服务';
  aLangKeys['ch']['sem'] = '谷歌与雅虎推广';
  aLangKeys['ch']['webdev'] = '品牌网站建设';
  aLangKeys['ch']['app'] = 'APP 开发';
  aLangKeys['ch']['tbd'] = '加拿大工商业与市场拓展';
  aLangKeys['ch']['ourteam'] = '我们的团队';
  aLangKeys['ch']['contactus'] = '联络我们';
  aLangKeys['ch']['submit'] = '发留言';
  aLangKeys['ch']['reset'] = '重新';



})(jQuery);
```

```html
<!-- Header -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<header id="header" class="alt">
  <h1>
    <a href="index.html"> <img src="images/Artboard%201.png" alt="logo" class="logo"> </a>
  </h1>
  <nav id="nav">
    <ul class="translate">
      <li><a href="index.html" key="home" class="tr">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="AboutUs.html" key="about" class="tr">About Us</a></li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="submenu fa-angle-down tr" key="serv">Services</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="SEM.html" key="sem" class="tr">Search Engine Marketing</a></li>
          <li><a href="WebDev.html" key="webdev" class="tr">Website Development </a></li>
          <li><a href="AppDev.html" key="app" class="tr">App Development</a></li>
          <li><a href="Automation.html" key="tbd" class="tr">Technical Business Development</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="ourteam.html" key="ourteam" class="tr">Our Team</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" id="en" class="button lang">English</a></li>
      <li><a href="#" id="ch" class="button lang">中文</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact" class="button tr" key="contactus">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>

  </nav>

</header>

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Here is the other part of JS code:

```js
(function($) {

  /**
   * Generate an indented list of links from a nav. Meant for use with panel().
   * @return {jQuery} jQuery object.
   */
  $.fn.navList = function() {

    var $this = $(this);
    $a = $this.find('a'),
      b = [];

    $a.each(function() {

      var $this = $(this),
        indent = Math.max(0, $this.parents('li').length - 1),
        href = $this.attr('href'),
        target = $this.attr('target');

      b.push(
        '<a ' +
        'class="link depth-' + indent + '"' +
        ((typeof target !== 'undefined' && target != '') ? ' target="' + target + '"' : '') +
        ((typeof href !== 'undefined' && href != '') ? ' href="' + href + '"' : '') +
        '>' +
        '<span class="indent-' + indent + '"></span>' +
        $this.text() +
        '</a>'
      );

    });

    return b.join('');

  };

  /**
   * Panel-ify an element.
   * @param {object} userConfig User config.
   * @return {jQuery} jQuery object.
   */
  $.fn.panel = function(userConfig) {

    // No elements?
    if (this.length == 0)
      return $this;

    // Multiple elements?
    if (this.length > 1) {

      for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++)
        $(this[i]).panel(userConfig);

      return $this;

    }

    // Vars.
    var $this = $(this),
      $body = $('body'),
      $window = $(window),
      id = $this.attr('id'),
      config;

    // Config.
    config = $.extend({

      // Delay.
      delay: 0,

      // Hide panel on link click.
      hideOnClick: false,

      // Hide panel on escape keypress.
      hideOnEscape: false,

      // Hide panel on swipe.
      hideOnSwipe: false,

      // Reset scroll position on hide.
      resetScroll: false,

      // Reset forms on hide.
      resetForms: false,

      // Side of viewport the panel will appear.
      side: null,

      // Target element for "class".
      target: $this,

      // Class to toggle.
      visibleClass: 'visible'

    }, userConfig);

    // Expand "target" if it's not a jQuery object already.
    if (typeof config.target != 'jQuery')
      config.target = $(config.target);

    // Panel.

    // Methods.
    $this._hide = function(event) {

      // Already hidden? Bail.
      if (!config.target.hasClass(config.visibleClass))
        return;

      // If an event was provided, cancel it.
      if (event) {

        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();

      }

      // Hide.
      config.target.removeClass(config.visibleClass);

      // Post-hide stuff.
      window.setTimeout(function() {

        // Reset scroll position.
        if (config.resetScroll)
          $this.scrollTop(0);

        // Reset forms.
        if (config.resetForms)
          $this.find('form').each(function() {
            this.reset();
          });

      }, config.delay);

    };

    // Vendor fixes.
    $this
      .css('-ms-overflow-style', '-ms-autohiding-scrollbar')
      .css('-webkit-overflow-scrolling', 'touch');

    // Hide on click.
    if (config.hideOnClick) {

      $this.find('a')
        .css('-webkit-tap-highlight-color', 'rgba(0,0,0,0)');

      $this
        .on('click', 'a', function(event) {

          var $a = $(this),
            href = $a.attr('href'),
            target = $a.attr('target');

          if (!href || href == '#' || href == '' || href == '#' + id)
            return;

          // Cancel original event.
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();

          // Hide panel.
          $this._hide();

          // Redirect to href.
          window.setTimeout(function() {

            if (target == '_blank')
              window.open(href);
            else
              window.location.href = href;

          }, config.delay + 10);

        });

    }

    // Event: Touch stuff.
    $this.on('touchstart', function(event) {

      $this.touchPosX = event.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX;
      $this.touchPosY = event.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY;

    })

    $this.on('touchmove', function(event) {

      if ($this.touchPosX === null ||
        $this.touchPosY === null)
        return;

      var diffX = $this.touchPosX - event.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX,
        diffY = $this.touchPosY - event.originalEvent.touches[0].pageY,
        th = $this.outerHeight(),
        ts = ($this.get(0).scrollHeight - $this.scrollTop());

      // Hide on swipe?
      if (config.hideOnSwipe) {

        var result = false,
          boundary = 20,
          delta = 50;

        switch (config.side) {

          case 'left':
            result = (diffY < boundary && diffY > (-1 * boundary)) && (diffX > delta);
            break;

          case 'right':
            result = (diffY < boundary && diffY > (-1 * boundary)) && (diffX < (-1 * delta));
            break;

          case 'top':
            result = (diffX < boundary && diffX > (-1 * boundary)) && (diffY > delta);
            break;

          case 'bottom':
            result = (diffX < boundary && diffX > (-1 * boundary)) && (diffY < (-1 * delta));
            break;

          default:
            break;

        }

        if (result) {

          $this.touchPosX = null;
          $this.touchPosY = null;
          $this._hide();

          return false;

        }

      }

      // Prevent vertical scrolling past the top or bottom.
      if (($this.scrollTop() < 0 && diffY < 0) ||
        (ts > (th - 2) && ts < (th + 2) && diffY > 0)) {

        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();

      }

    });

    // Event: Prevent certain events inside the panel from bubbling.
    $this.on('click touchend touchstart touchmove', function(event) {
      event.stopPropagation();
    });

    // Event: Hide panel if a child anchor tag pointing to its ID is clicked.
    $this.on('click', 'a[href="#' + id + '"]', function(event) {

      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();

      config.target.removeClass(config.visibleClass);

    });

    // Body.

    // Event: Hide panel on body click/tap.
    $body.on('click touchend', function(event) {
      $this._hide(event);
    });

    // Event: Toggle.
    $body.on('click', 'a[href="#' + id + '"]', function(event) {

      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();

      config.target.toggleClass(config.visibleClass);

    });

    // Window.

    // Event: Hide on ESC.
    if (config.hideOnEscape)
      $window.on('keydown', function(event) {

        if (event.keyCode == 27)
          $this._hide(event);

      });

    return $this;

  };

  /**
   * Apply "placeholder" attribute polyfill to one or more forms.
   * @return {jQuery} jQuery object.
   */
  $.fn.placeholder = function() {

    // Browser natively supports placeholders? Bail.
    if (typeof(document.createElement('input')).placeholder != 'undefined')
      return $(this);

    // No elements?
    if (this.length == 0)
      return $this;

    // Multiple elements?
    if (this.length > 1) {

      for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++)
        $(this[i]).placeholder();

      return $this;

    }

    // Vars.
    var $this = $(this);

    // Text, TextArea.
    $this.find('input[type=text],textarea')
      .each(function() {

        var i = $(this);

        if (i.val() == '' ||
          i.val() == i.attr('placeholder'))
          i
          .addClass('polyfill-placeholder')
          .val(i.attr('placeholder'));

      })
      .on('blur', function() {

        var i = $(this);

        if (i.attr('name').match(/-polyfill-field$/))
          return;

        if (i.val() == '')
          i
          .addClass('polyfill-placeholder')
          .val(i.attr('placeholder'));

      })
      .on('focus', function() {

        var i = $(this);

        if (i.attr('name').match(/-polyfill-field$/))
          return;

        if (i.val() == i.attr('placeholder'))
          i
          .removeClass('polyfill-placeholder')
          .val('');

      });

    // Password.
    $this.find('input[type=password]')
      .each(function() {

        var i = $(this);
        var x = $(
          $('<div>')
          .append(i.clone())
          .remove()
          .html()
          .replace(/type="password"/i, 'type="text"')
          .replace(/type=password/i, 'type=text')
        );

        if (i.attr('id') != '')
          x.attr('id', i.attr('id') + '-polyfill-field');

        if (i.attr('name') != '')
          x.attr('name', i.attr('name') + '-polyfill-field');

        x.addClass('polyfill-placeholder')
          .val(x.attr('placeholder')).insertAfter(i);

        if (i.val() == '')
          i.hide();
        else
          x.hide();

        i
          .on('blur', function(event) {

            event.preventDefault();

            var x = i.parent().find('input[name=' + i.attr('name') + '-polyfill-field]');

            if (i.val() == '') {

              i.hide();
              x.show();

            }

          });

        x
          .on('focus', function(event) {

            event.preventDefault();

            var i = x.parent().find('input[name=' + x.attr('name').replace('-polyfill-field', '') + ']');

            x.hide();

            i
              .show()
              .focus();

          })
          .on('keypress', function(event) {

            event.preventDefault();
            x.val('');

          });

      });

    // Events.
    $this
      .on('submit', function() {

        $this.find('input[type=text],input[type=password],textarea')
          .each(function(event) {

            var i = $(this);

            if (i.attr('name').match(/-polyfill-field$/))
              i.attr('name', '');

            if (i.val() == i.attr('placeholder')) {

              i.removeClass('polyfill-placeholder');
              i.val('');

            }

          });

      })
      .on('reset', function(event) {

        event.preventDefault();

        $this.find('select')
          .val($('option:first').val());

        $this.find('input,textarea')
          .each(function() {

            var i = $(this),
              x;

            i.removeClass('polyfill-placeholder');

            switch (this.type) {

              case 'submit':
              case 'reset':
                break;

              case 'password':
                i.val(i.attr('defaultValue'));

                x = i.parent().find('input[name=' + i.attr('name') + '-polyfill-field]');

                if (i.val() == '') {
                  i.hide();
                  x.show();
                } else {
                  i.show();
                  x.hide();
                }

                break;

              case 'checkbox':
              case 'radio':
                i.attr('checked', i.attr('defaultValue'));
                break;

              case 'text':
              case 'textarea':
                i.val(i.attr('defaultValue'));

                if (i.val() == '') {
                  i.addClass('polyfill-placeholder');
                  i.val(i.attr('placeholder'));
                }

                break;

              default:
                i.val(i.attr('defaultValue'));
                break;

            }
          });

      });

    return $this;

  };

  /**
   * Moves elements to/from the first positions of their respective parents.
   * @param {jQuery} $elements Elements (or selector) to move.
   * @param {bool} condition If true, moves elements to the top. Otherwise, moves elements back to their original locations.
   */
  $.prioritize = function($elements, condition) {

    var key = '__prioritize';

    // Expand $elements if it's not already a jQuery object.
    if (typeof $elements != 'jQuery')
      $elements = $($elements);

    // Step through elements.
    $elements.each(function() {

      var $e = $(this),
        $p,
        $parent = $e.parent();

      // No parent? Bail.
      if ($parent.length == 0)
        return;

      // Not moved? Move it.
      if (!$e.data(key)) {

        // Condition is false? Bail.
        if (!condition)
          return;

        // Get placeholder (which will serve as our point of reference for when this element needs to move back).
        $p = $e.prev();

        // Couldn't find anything? Means this element's already at the top, so bail.
        if ($p.length == 0)
          return;

        // Move element to top of parent.
        $e.prependTo($parent);

        // Mark element as moved.
        $e.data(key, $p);

      }

      // Moved already?
      else {

        // Condition is true? Bail.
        if (condition)
          return;

        $p = $e.data(key);

        // Move element back to its original location (using our placeholder).
        $e.insertAfter($p);

        // Unmark element as moved.
        $e.removeData(key);

      }

    });

  };


})(jQuery);
```

Here is the code snippet of my dropotron jquery file I have been using for the menu drop down if needed.

Where would I go to insert my lang class so that when it is in mobile nav the class is recognized? Thank you!

Comment: You haven't given us all of your JavaScript code - please add the relevant code.

Comment: I apologize! I have added the whole main.js code

Comment: So if I understand what you want to do, you want your website to be mobile friendly?  If so they your resolution is to transform the page to the size of the mobile device? If both of these are correct, then your solution, while admirable, is not how 99% of website are designed.

Comment: My main goal I am trying to solve right now is just why those two buttons (class lang) don't work when clicked on in the mobile nav (when screen width goes below X) :)

Comment: I have solved it! I needed to add the class tr into 'class="link depth-' + indent + '"' + ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!

I needed to add the class 'tr' into:

'class="**tr** link depth-' + indent + '"' +

Just forgot that little thing...